# What is the most efficient way to connect a web UI to Apache HBase?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I'm new to **Apache HBase and BigData.** I'm currently working on a model which has a web UI and apache HBase as the backend database. Other layers of the app i.e. the Service layer and the DAO layer are written in `Java`. A basic control flow diagram is as shown here:[Control flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhyez.jpg)

1. Data is inserted into the HBase by an independent program.
2. The main problem comes during the retrieval stage. Every time when the user performs some action on the UI and submits a form, the call is delegated from **UI to service layer to DAO layer** and intern, hbase calls are made in DAO layer.
3. This has slowed down the entire process. User has to wait for a longer period of timie while requesting for huge data.

I wanted to know the possible ways in which this can be handled in a better and efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in systems where you have data ingest in one side and direct querying from an application you will need to enable difference access paths to scale (indexes).  We have that capability at Splice Machine (Open Source) if you are interested.

I would also suggest if you can get to a standard (SQL, etc.), then your options will open up.

Good luck.